# Doing inverse limit reflection from an $I_0$ embedding to an $I_1$ embedding

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Suppose that $j:L(V_{\lambda+1}) \rightarrow L(V_{\lambda+1})$ with critical point $\kappa<\lambda$. Then $\kappa$ is a limit of cardinals $\kappa'<\kappa$ such that $I_1(\kappa',\delta)$ for a $\delta<\kappa$, I believe. I'm trying to get clear about whether any form of the axiom of choice is needed to prove this and if so how it comes up.

Comment: What's/where's "the usual proof" with choice? Couldn't find it in Kanamori.

Comment: Yes, true, I don't think it is in Kanamori, but I think it is given in a paper of Cramer's on inverse limit reflection, which I should probably try to read and understand.